# Build static library in Xcode 4. What happen with ${BUILD_STYLE}?

Tags: xcode, static

I use Xcode 4.2. I'm building a static framework.

I built 2 libs: lib-simulator.a for simulator, lib-iphoneos.a for device.

In the aggregate target, I put the script:

> rm -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libAggregate.a
>
> lipo -create
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/../${BUILD_STYLE}-iphonesimulator/liblib-simulator.a"
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/liblib-iphoneos.a" -output
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libAggregate.a"

Then I build the aggregate target, it failed. The log below:

> lipo: can't open input file:
>   /Users/vietnt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testCreateLib-ftdlqzrlflzkkkczafzhqrvxvgkx/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/../**-iphonesimulator**/lib-simulator.a
>   (No such file or directory)

I see there is a lack of rendering the ${BUILD_STYLE} in to the command as the bold word.

If I build my project in Xcode 3.2.6, it's OK, then generate the libAggregate.a file.

Please help me. Thank you!

EDIT:

I resolved that.

**${BUILD_STYLE}** is changed to **${CONFIGURATION}** in Xcode 4

Happy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved that.

${BUILD_STYLE} is changed to ${CONFIGURATION} in Xcode 4

Happy!

Comment: Do we need to make any change to the script or to Scheme in Xcode? Ca you explain how did you fix this problem?